# How do I use "included" files in an MSpec test run?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, mspec

I have a test project and I'm using MSpec for some of the tests (mixed project with both MSpec and VSTest). I have a method that operates on a text file and requires a path to the file. My problem is that the current directory for the file doesn't include the file I need. I have the file included in my project, marked as content & "copy always".

After the test run I can see the file in the `TestResults/[timestamped folder]/Out` directory. However, if I debug the test and check `Path.GetFullPath("resources\\myfile.txt")` in the immediate window it returns:

```
"C:\\Users\\[username]\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\cb44d906-d20b-4bfb-9569-c661986eb902\\cb44d906-d20b-4bfb-9569-c661986eb902\\assembly\\dl3\\5e87e3e4\\e2bffa3c_7daacf01\\resources\\myfile.txt"
```

Am I using MSpec wrong? Or am I just missing some configuration?

Visual Studio 2013, runner: ("MSpec Test Adapter" VS extension by Eugene Duvenage)

Comment: So I just modified my api to accept the content of the file (string or stream) instead of the path. Now I can use an embedded resource. However, I'd still like to get a better answer to this if anyone is willing.

Comment: This is very likely due to shadow-copying the spec assembly. Can you turn it off somewhere in the test adapter settings if such settings are provided?